# How to prevent solution folder tag from creating directory(folders) in solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-templates

I'm trying to Create Multi-Project Templates. I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx instructions but with the following structure it creates folder for "Core" and "Web". I need to add Solution Folders as virtual folders because they are not really created in the Filesystem and projects inside solution folders are just sitting in the same folder as the .sln file.

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>DT.WhiteLabel</Name>
        <Description>Dt digital White label project</Description>
        <Icon>dt.png</Icon>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
     <SolutionFolder Name="Core">
          <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="DT.Data">
              DT.Data\MyTemplate.vstemplate
          </ProjectTemplateLink>
          <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="DT.Services">
              DT.Services\MyTemplate.vstemplate
          </ProjectTemplateLink>
       </SolutionFolder>
       <SolutionFolder Name="Web">
          <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="DT.Web.MVC">
              DT.Web.MVC\MyTemplate.vstemplate
          </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </SolutionFolder>
          <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="DT.ExportCSV">
              DT.ExportCSV\MyTemplate.vstemplate
          </ProjectTemplateLink>  
        </ProjectCollection>
<WizardExtension>

    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
<WizardData>
  <packages  repository="extension" repositoryId="DT.WhiteLabel..7c9d41b1-2f6e-4210-9340-a5bfc00f4800">
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="2.2.0" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" />
  <package id="Elmah.MVC" version="2.0.2" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="4.1.10331.0" />
  <package id="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" version="0.85.4.369" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.5.1" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.11" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.0" />
  <package id="jQuery.vsdoc" version="1.5.1" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="1.7" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.0.1.10" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC3" version="3.0.0.6" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.0.0.7" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.2" />
  </packages>
</WizardData>
    </TemplateContent>

</VSTemplate>
```

[image]

I'm looking for

[image]

What I get at the moment
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also the post is older than 6 months, I think my answer is usefull for other people.
I solved this problem with a wizard, in which I create the needed solution folders in the "Run Finished" method. After this I save the projects fullnames in a string list and remove them from the solution. Then I add the projects to the solution folder with help of the saved fullnames. It might be complicated, but it works ;-) 
I think good tutorials for creating a wizard are http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2012/01/05/Creating-custom-project-and-file-template-with-wizard-for-Visual-Studio.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15268/How-to-Create-Your-own-Visual-Studio-Wizard